# Github pages doesn't display any content

Tags: github, github-pages

I'm new to Github and this is the second time I'm trying to upload a project and I get the same result; The page seems to show the readme file and nothing else. I have tried using the master as well as gh-pages branches and nothing changed. I'm really not sure what I'm doing wrong and would be grateful if I get my first answer in Stackoverflow here.  
repo: https://github.com/Syknapse/RGB-Color-Changing-Game

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's because the outer directory which your initial URL refers to contains only the Readme.md.Your HTML file to be displayed is in the folder RGB Game files.I would suggest you to either bring your static files in the outermost directory or change the name of your directory into something url friendly(read not containing spaces) and then enter the 'URL/filename'.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, I will try this now

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working. I have moved the files to the outer directory, and still I'm getting the same result. https://syknapse.github.io/RGB-Color-Changing-Game/

Comment: putting my html in the outermost directory and calling it index.html finally resolved the problem. I'm not sure though if the name of the html file is relevant. So I'm marking this as the right answer. Thanks